# Proof of Existence of a (Planar) Triangle Given Three Sides

Tags: geometry

Suppose that a triangle is required to have perimeter $1$, with sides $a,b,c.$ I would like to show the following:
$$a+b\ge .5$$
$$b+c\ge .5$$
$$c+a\ge .5$$

I have already proven necessity, but I don't immediately see sufficiency.

To prove necessity, assume that $a+b < .5$ but then $c\ge .5$, now draw a "degenerate triangle" where the three segments all fall on a single line, this cannot produced a triangle (the image is not "closed", there are "three" vertice). And of course, in the nondegenerate case the triangle still can't be produced.

I was thinking of using law of cosines somehow to prove sufficiency, but not sure..... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You won't find sufficiency unless one or two of the inequalities is strict:

E.g. $$a+c = 1,\quad a+b = 0.5,\quad b + c = 0.5\;$$ satisfies the inequalities you've written, but they are necessarily all points on a line: on a generate triangle of "length/perimeter" $= 1.$

Comment: Sorry.I don't see how this proves the case in general.  I see that it proves for some subset of the inequality's sample space, I don't understand why this proves for everything... unless you are saying that any perturbation from this is "obviously" a triangle?

Comment: I am simply stating that one can meet the criteria/satisfy your inequalities, and still fail to be a triangle (or to be realized only as a degenerate triangle). Hence, your inequalities, together with the summing to 1, as currently stated, *are not* sufficient to determine a non-degenerate triangle, and hence, cannot be proven to be sufficient, unless you alter the inequalities.

Comment: I am allowing degenerate triangles (i.e. lines), so it's not a problem for me, my only real issue is that every end of any line segment must be touching another line segment (so for example, not any line of the three segments laying on each other is a triangle, for a line to be considered a triangle -- for my purposes -- the segments, as defined, must each meet at the vertices once per end).
So with the fact that I allow degenerate triangles, do you believe now that my inequalities are correct (sufficient)?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You've got it. Allowing for the degenerate case, you're inequalities are sufficient to ensure a triangle, though I think you'd more clearly rule out the example you give, and the degenerate case, by stating that the sum of the lengths of the line segments $=1$. I.e., the perimeter, but by stating the sum of the lengths of the line segments strictly 1, you rule out the degenerate case (sum of lengths of the segments in my "counterexample" is $2$, and you'd rule out the overlapping case, sum > 1

Comment: Does this last comment help assure you? Instead of saying "perimeter = 1", you can get that but more if you state: $a + b + c = 1$. Then, for example in the degenerate case, although perimeter (net distance) is 1, $a + b + c = 2$, and hence would be ruled out by the latter.

Comment: @amWhy: After some very nice discourse, not sure they got it! =1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care about the marginal degenerate case amWhy refers to - I prefer a constructive geometrical approach to proving existence.

First of all, start by drawing a line of length $a$ horizontally. Now you attach (WLOG) $b, c$ to the left, right of $a$. Where are the possible endpoints for these lines? They form a nice pair of loci. Where these intersect must be where you can put the final vertex.

Then you just need to use your relations to check whether or not they do, in fact, intersect! You will need all three relations (unless you're clever about which edge you choose first).

Answer (score 0):

As amWhy pointed out, you might need strict inequalities. Assuming they are strict,

Asume $0 \lt a \le b \le c$ and $a+b+c = 1$

Now $a + b \gt 0.5 \implies a + b \ge \frac{a+b+c}{2} \implies a+b \gt c$

Thus $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle.

If you allow degenerate triangles, then you can drop the strictness.